# ESP32 Wifiserver and Android Appp

Tags: java, android, wifi, android-wifi, esp32

So i got my ESP32 and wanted to do some Porjects and I want to control them with an Android App, for example LED Stripes. I already did this with my Raspberry Pi where it runs perfectly.
I already tried some codes and it could connect to the Wifi. And my PC and even Raspberry Pi could connect to it but when i tried with my Smartphone i just didn't worked.
Here' my Android Code:
mainActivity.jre

```
connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!IPAddress.getText().equals("") || IPAddress.getText() != null || !portNumber.getText().equals("") || portNumber.getText() != null){
                    return;
                }

                IPaddresse= IPAddress.getText().toString();
                port=Integer.parseInt(portNumber.getText().toString());

                try {
                    client = new Socket(IPaddresse,port);
                    pw = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
                    dataOutputStream= new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                    msg.setText("Verbunden!");
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

ESP32 Code:

```
#include <WiFi.h>

const char* ssid="Name";
const char* password="password";

WiFiServer server(80  );

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("start");
  
  delay(1000);
 
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }
 
  Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
 
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
 
  if (client) {
 
    while (client.connected()) {
 
      while (client.available()>0) {
        char c = client.read();
        client.write(c);
      }

      Serial.println(client.localIP());
      delay(10);
    }
  }
  
}
```

Sorry for my English. And my Code isn't the best im just beginning to Code
Thanks

Comment: `but when i tried with my Smartphone i just didn't worked. ` Indeed. Didn' you see:  `NetworkOnMainThreadException` ?

Comment: No i didn't see any exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>First on the ESP32 i suggest you add mDNS to your setup, this allows you to give your esp a name on the network like when you give your esp the name *pietje* then you can find it as *pietje.local* on your network.</del>
This seems not to work properly with the socket class, but maybe i did something work. It did not finding the ip of it. It was the first time working with sockets. So i learned something new.

I tried your example and it did fault me to. With some short search i found this website:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sending-and-receiving-data-with-sockets-in-android
By adding you socket creation inside a thread it did work for me.

I hope this helps you ahead.